# How to install msbuild on CentOs

Tags: msbuild, centos, mono, xbuild

I want to install msbuild on CentOS to run project.sln files. What are the commands for installing the same. I tried to install using "didstopia/msbuild" docker image but could not succeed.

Comment: Your first task is to assert if that solution file can be used on CentOS. Most won’t support CentOS unless its authors do test against either Mono or .NET Core.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install the [*dotnet sdk*](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/linux-package-manager/centos/sdk-current) for centOS.
You will be able to run **msbuild** files with the command `dotnet msbuild` or even just `dotnet`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I tried installing dotnet sdk and i tried running msbuild command and got the below error. Can you please suggest me regarding this.                        

[deshpand@ess-danik37 angebotsapp]$ dotnet msbuild .

/home/deshpand/angebotsapp/kommmit.Offers/kommmit.Offers.Android/kommmit.Offers.Android.csproj(393,3): error MSB4019: The imported project "/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/2.2.104/Novell/Novell.MonoDroid.CSharp.targets" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.

Comment: @user3248113 That is another question. You succeed to install and run `msbuild`, and now you have a compile/build problem with your project.